# Return foreach values inside string

Tags: php, arrays

I have the code below. I am trying to loop through an array within a string and return the results to be a sub part of the string.

```
    $household = '{
                "data": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "name":"'.rgar( $entry, '1.6' ).'"
                    },
                    "relationships": {
                        "people":{
                            "data":[
                                '.
                                foreach ($family_ids[] as $fam_member){
                                    return '{"type":"Person","id":"'.$fam_member.'"}';
                                }.'
                            ]
                        },
                        "primary_contact":{
                            "data":{"type":"Person","id":"1"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }';

            echo($household);
```

My expected results would be along the lines of this

```
        '{
                "data": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "name":"'.rgar( $entry, '1.6' ).'"
                    },
                    "relationships": {
                        "people":{
                            "data":[
                                {"type":"Person","id":"2"},
                                {"type":"Person","id":"3"},
                                {"type":"Person","id":"4"}, //note the commas
                                {"type":"Person","id":"5"}
                            ]
                        },
                        "primary_contact":{
                            "data":{"type":"Person","id":"1"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }';
```

I believe my issue is related to my quotation marks to break in and out of the string. However I am also not sure how to address to comma being removed for the last result.

Comment: you can not do in that way. create a variable. assign foreach iteration value to that variable and then assign this variable to your json array

Comment: It's not a good idea to build Json string by hand. It's better to build an array and convert it to json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign foreach value to a variable first and then assign this variable to your json.

```
$data = [];

foreach ($family_ids as $fam_member){
    $data[]= ["type"=>"Person","id"=> $fam_member]
}


$household = '{
                "data": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "name":"'.rgar( $entry, '1.6' ).'"
                    },
                    "relationships": {
                        "people":{
                            "data":'. json_encode($data) . '
                        },
                        "primary_contact":{
                            "data":{"type":"Person","id":"1"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }';

echo($household);
```

A hardcoded sample example Output:- https://3v4l.org/enrGP

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate `$household` variable in such a way like this. Although @AliveToDie's solution is best but this solution will be easy to understand for beginners

```
$household = '';
    $household .= '{
           "data": {
               "attributes": {
                   "name":"'.rgar( $entry, '1.6' ).'"
               },
               "relationships": {
                   "people":{
                       "data":[
                           ';

                           foreach ($family_ids[] as $key => $fam_member){
                            $household .= '{"type":"Person","id":"'.$fam_member.'"}';
                                if((count($family_ids)-1)!=$key)// if foreach loop reaches the last element then it won't print the comma
                                     $household .= ',';
                            }

        $household .='
                       ]
                   },
                   "primary_contact":{
                       "data":{"type":"Person","id":"1"}
                   }
               }
           }
       }';
 echo($household);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for building a json string by escaping your quotes?

Perhaps this solution (which I think will give you more freedom, and you don't have to worry about escaping quotes etc) would be beneficial to you:

```
$household['data']['attributes']['name']              = rgar( $entry, '1.6' );
$household['data']['relationships']['people']['data'] = array(); // In case $family_ids is empty

foreach ($family_ids[] as $fam_member):
  $household['data']['relationships']['people']['data'][] = array(
    'type' => 'Person',
    'id'   => $fam_member
  );
endforeach;

$household['data']['relationships']['primary_contact']['data'] = array(
  'type' => 'Person',
  'id'   => '1'
);

$json       = json_encode($household);
$prettyJson = json_encode($household, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $prettyJson;
```

Then, you can either use `$json` for your json, or, if you needed it to be formatted and pretty, you can use `$prettyJson`;